# glumpy.gloo bind texture as GL_RGB32F

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, glumpy

I'm using [Glumpy](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy) and I'm trying to bind a texture as `GL_RGB32F`. It appears that it binds the texture as `GL_RGB`, even though my numpy array is of type `np.float32`. The values this array contains are outside the 0..1 range, and I need these values in a fragment shader unclipped.

```
compute = gloo.Program(compute_vertex, compute_fragment, count=4)
compute["matte"] = matte
compute["matte"].interpolation = gl.GL_NEAREST
compute["matte"].wrapping = gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
compute["distanceField"] = alpha
compute["distanceField"].interpolation = gl.GL_NEAREST
compute["distanceField"].wrapping = gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
compute["position"] = [(-1, -1), (-1, +1), (+1, -1), (+1, +1)]
compute["texcoord"] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

print(matte.dtype)
print(gl.GL_RGB32F)
print(compute["matte"].gpu_format)
print(compute["distanceField"].gpu_format)
```

The output is

```
float32
GL_RGB32F (34837)
GL_RGB (6407)
GL_RED (6403)
```

How can I bind the `matte` array as `GL_RGB32F` and the `distanceField` as `GL_R32F`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use `view(gloo.TextureFloat2D)` on the numpy array, otherwise, internally it would automatically call `view(Texture2D)`.

```
compute = gloo.Program(compute_vertex, compute_fragment, count=4)
compute["matte"] = matte.view(gloo.TextureFloat2D)
compute["matte"].interpolation = gl.GL_NEAREST
compute["matte"].wrapping = gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
compute["distanceField"] = alpha.view(gloo.TextureFloat2D)
compute["distanceField"].interpolation = gl.GL_NEAREST
compute["distanceField"].wrapping = gl.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
compute["position"] = [(-1, -1), (-1, +1), (+1, -1), (+1, +1)]
compute["texcoord"] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```